# Wait for ajax request inside a function : $.Deferred ? $.When ? jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, deferred, resolve, .when

**How to wait until the ajax is done inside a deferred function ? Example :**

```
    function action() {
        console.log('action is called');

        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        console.log('do some actions...');

        //Wait until the ajax is completed and continue script
        var myAjaxCall = ajaxCall();

        //Execute te next scripts only after the ajax done

        console.log('do some actions...');

        return deferred.promise();
    }


    function ajaxCall() {
        console.log('ajaxCall is called');

        return $.ajax('url').then(function() {
            console.log('success  ajaxCall');
        });
    }

    action().then(function () {
        console.log('after action is done and ajaxCall is done');
    });
```

The probleme is that he function must wait until the ajax inside is called and done and continue other scripts.

Thank you.

Comment: You never resolve the `Deferred` inside the `action` function.

Answer (score 3):

You can chain promise `then()`'s.

Also there is no need to create a new promise when `$.ajax` already returns one

So inside `action()` you can do something like:

```
 function action() {
    console.log('action is called'); 

    var myAjaxCall = ajaxCall();

     return myAjaxCall.then(function(result){
        // do stuff here after ajax is successfull  
     });
}
```

Comment: But the action() is called inside anoter function that contain deferred.

Comment: no idea what that means...that's not what is shown in question

Comment: Thank you anyway for your answers